# MYSQL server not started after installation from source code

Tags: mysql, installation

I installed mysql thorugh source code .I followed all instruction from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/installing-source-distribution.html
but after installation when i am trying to start mmysql server ,It is giving me below error:

```
[root@sumit bin]# ./mysqld_safe &
[1] 25798
[root@sumit bin]# 130904 19:07:29 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysqld.log'.

130904 19:07:29 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql

130904 19:07:30 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

This is the mysqld.log file content :

```
130904 20:02:01 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
2013-09-04 20:02:02 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2013-09-04 20:02:02 31995 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
2013-09-04 20:02:02 31995 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
2013-09-04 20:02:02 31995 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2013-09-04 20:02:02 31995 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2013-09-04 20:02:02 31995 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2013-09-04 20:02:02 31995 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2013-09-04 20:02:02 31995 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2013-09-04 20:02:02 31995 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2013-09-04 20:02:02 31995 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2013-09-04 20:02:02 31995 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 49463
2013-09-04 20:02:02 31995 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2013-09-04 20:02:02 31995 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2013-09-04 20:02:02 31995 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2013-09-04 20:02:02 31995 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages
2013-09-04 20:02:02 31995 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 1600607
2013-09-04 20:02:02 31995 [Note] InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percent: 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99
InnoDB: Apply batch completed
2013-09-04 20:02:03 31995 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2013-09-04 20:02:03 31995 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2013-09-04 20:02:03 31995 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.13 started; log sequence number 1600607
2013-09-04 20:02:03 31995 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2013-09-04 20:02:03 31995 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2013-09-04 20:02:03 31995 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2013-09-04 20:02:03 31995 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2013-09-04 20:02:03 31995 [ERROR] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
2013-09-04 20:02:03 31995 [ERROR] Can't start server: can't create PID file: Permission denied
130904 20:02:03 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

Comment: And what about to try `tail -n 20 /var/log/mysqld.log` ?

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo Please check the log content in the question itself.

Comment: Is it unclear from the log listing what to do?