# Can't start MySQL server for the first time

Tags: mysql

I recently downloaded and installed MySQL Server 5.6 Community Edition for Windows 7. I verified that all of the following was installed:

MySQL Workbench 6.0 CE
MySQL Connector 6.7.4
MySQL Connector Python
MySQL Connector Installer
MySQL Notifier 1.1.4
MySQL Server 5.6
MySQL Utilties

To run MySQL Server for the first time I used the instructions at:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/windows-server-first-start.html

and the command:

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld"
```

It was unable to start and I was given the following error. *** Corrected, see further below ***

```
2013-09-12 22:14:47 10768 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2013-09-12 22:14:47 10768 [Warning] option 'innodb-autoextend-increment': unsigned value 67108864 adjusted to 1000
2013-09-12 22:14:47 3a14 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2013-09-12 22:14:48 10768 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2013-09-12 22:14:48 10768 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2013-09-12 22:14:48 10768 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2013-09-12 22:14:48 10768 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2013-09-12 22:14:48 10768 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 45.0M
2013-09-12 22:14:48 10768 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2013-09-12 22:14:49 10768 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2013-09-12 22:14:50 10768 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2013-09-12 22:14:50 10768 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2013-09-12 22:14:50 10768 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.13 started; log sequence number 8525811
2013-09-12 22:14:50 10768 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2013-09-12 22:14:50 10768 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2013-09-12 22:14:50 10768 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2013-09-12 22:14:50 10768 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2013-09-12 22:14:52 10768 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2013-09-12 22:14:52 10768 [Note] C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.6/bin\mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.13'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

*** From the command prompt ***

```
C:\>"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld"
2013-09-12 23:39:36 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is depreca
ted. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentati
on for more details).
2013-09-12 23:39:36 14452 [Warning] Can't create test file C:\Program Files\MySQ
L\MySQL Server 5.6\data\Stinker.lower-test
2013-09-12 23:39:36 14452 [Warning] Can't create test file C:\Program Files\MySQ
L\MySQL Server 5.6\data\Stinker.lower-test
2013-09-12 23:39:36 14452 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2013-09-12 23:39:36 14452 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2013-09-12 23:39:36 14452 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interl
ocked functions
2013-09-12 23:39:36 14452 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2013-09-12 23:39:36 14452 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2013-09-12 23:39:36 14452 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M

2013-09-12 23:39:36 14452 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool

2013-09-12 23:39:36 14452 [ERROR] InnoDB: .\ibdata1 can't be opened in read-writ
e mode
2013-09-12 23:39:36 14452 [ERROR] InnoDB: The system tablespace must be writable
!
2013-09-12 23:39:36 14452 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2013-09-12 23:39:36 14452 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGI
NE failed.
2013-09-12 23:39:36 14452 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2013-09-12 23:39:36 14452 [ERROR] Aborting

2013-09-12 23:39:36 14452 [Note] Binlog end
2013-09-12 23:39:36 14452 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2013-09-12 23:39:36 14452 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2013-09-12 23:39:36 14452 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2013-09-12 23:39:36 14452 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2013-09-12 23:39:36 14452 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2013-09-12 23:39:36 14452 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2013-09-12 23:39:36 14452 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2013-09-12 23:39:36 14452 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2013-09-12 23:39:36 14452 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2013-09-12 23:39:36 14452 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2013-09-12 23:39:36 14452 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2013-09-12 23:39:36 14452 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2013-09-12 23:39:36 14452 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2013-09-12 23:39:36 14452 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2013-09-12 23:39:36 14452 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2013-09-12 23:39:36 14452 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2013-09-12 23:39:36 14452 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWOR
D'
2013-09-12 23:39:36 14452 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2013-09-12 23:39:36 14452 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'

2013-09-12 23:39:36 14452 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2013-09-12 23:39:36 14452 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2013-09-12 23:39:36 14452 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESE
T'
2013-09-12 23:39:36 14452 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2013-09-12 23:39:36 14452 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2013-09-12 23:39:36 14452 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2013-09-12 23:39:36 14452 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2013-09-12 23:39:36 14452 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2013-09-12 23:39:36 14452 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2013-09-12 23:39:36 14452 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2013-09-12 23:39:36 14452 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2013-09-12 23:39:36 14452 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2013-09-12 23:39:36 14452 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2013-09-12 23:39:36 14452 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2013-09-12 23:39:36 14452 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2013-09-12 23:39:36 14452 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2013-09-12 23:39:36 14452 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2013-09-12 23:39:36 14452 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2013-09-12 23:39:36 14452 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
2013-09-12 23:39:36 14452 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2013-09-12 23:39:36 14452 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2013-09-12 23:39:36 14452 [Note] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

I'm not sure what this means or where to turn to on fixing it. I checked the similar questions located on the right side of my screen before I sent this and none of them address this. The closest question similar to mine is this:

- [MYSQL server not started after installation from source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18615888/mysql-server-not-started-after-installation-from-source-code)

but it doesn't help.

Thoughts?

Comment: Those aren't errors in the log that you gave. Do you need to open up the firewall for port 3306?

Comment: IPv6 problems perhaps? What happens if you bind to 127.0.0.1 instead of `*`?

Comment: @Tim My goal is to run this all local. Do I need to open a port for that?

Comment: @Wrikken I'm not sure how to do that but I'll try if you give me the steps.

Comment: @user4014: nah, now we have more of the errors, we can see that `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data` is simply not writable for the user starting `mysqld`. Fix those permissions & you'll be allright. Forget about the IPv6 stuff I mentioned.

Comment: @Wrikken What is the best way to fix the permissions? I'm the owner and only user of this computer. I thought I had admin rights. Also, for my information, what part of the error log told you the path was not writable for the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a guess from my part:

```
Can't create test file C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\Stinker.lower-test
```

In Windows7 the program-files folder can only be written by users with administrative privileges after answering an UAC-prompt (if UAC is active). So as your data-folder is in that folder mysqld would have to run with administrator-rights and the process would have to be elevated somehow.

You could try changing your data-location by changing the `datadir =...` (and perhaps `innodb_data_home_dir` and `innodb_log_group_home_dir`) statement in your .ini-file or just install MySql to an other folder (might be easier for a first test) or turn off UAC.

**edit:** added UAC to better explain the situation

Comment: I am the owner and only user of the computer so I believe I am considered an admin. I checked the properties of the Data folder and clicked the Security tab to see permissions and Administrators have everything in the "Allow" column checked off and grayed out.

Comment: Ok, I've been a bit unclear: even for administrator-users any process writing to program-files has to be elevated via UAC. To test wether this is the issue either try installing mysql to another folder or turn off UAC (only temporarily for security reasons).